# Dedicated IP and hosting plan

Tags: ip, dedicated

I'm a hosting reseller at company example.com. They sell dedicated IP for USD 15 + SSH acces for another USD 5. Quite expensive for a starter like me.

Can I purchase dedicated IP from other website and assign this to my hosting clients as part of hosting plans I offered ?

Is this something you can do in WHM or Cpanel or it's not possible ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A Dedicated Hosting IP provides your hosting account and site a particular IP address, one that's not shared with any other accounts on precisely the same server. Therefore, in the event that you require access to your website if your DNS records are being propagated, or are planning to add an SSL Certificate, a Dedicated Hosting IP may be for you personally.
 hosting plan depend on client requirement. many hosting companies are service provider and they have many different hosting plan.